# Field Initialization Order with method that has side-effects

Tags: c#

I've looked around for a definitive answer to this question and can't seem to find one.  If someone could point me in the right-direction in terms of documentation, it would be greatly appreciated.

Now I fully understand the order of initialization of an object when it comes to construction, fields and inheritance etc, but can someone tell me the order of initialization of the following object:

```
public class foo
{
    private ECPoint point = new ECPoint() {
        X = MethodCall(),
        Y = MethodCall()
    }
}
```

Now in the above example, let's say that MethodCall() is reading from somewhere like a MemoryStream().  So each of the above two function calls has a side-effect of advancing the stream pointer.  My question is:  Is it **GUARANTEED** that X will be read and initialized before Y?

The reason I ask this question is because in C++ for example, if you have functions as arguments to a method, you can't guarantee the order in which those arguments are evaluated.  The ONLY guarantee you have is that they WILL be fully evaluated before the function is called.  Is it the same here?  In the above, are they initialized in order, or is the just a guarantee that X and Y will be fully evaluated before the construction of ECPoint?

Comment: Where is `X` and `Y` defined?

Comment: _" Is it GUARANTEED that X will be read and initialized before Y?"_ - I think you mean "`X` will be **assigned-to**, not "read" - there's no invocation of `X`'s getter here...

Comment: There is no function with parameters there. That's an object initialiser. It's just a nice way to write a constructor invocation followed by property assignments. The result is exactly the same as if you wrote the constructor invocation and property assignments separately.

Comment: @jmcilhinney They're not _exactly_ the same... but 99% the same, sure (the differences relate to exceptions: if the object is `IDisposable` and is constructed, but a property setter throws an exception, then the object won't be disposed (erk!) and the initializer target won't be assigned (making it impossible to eagerly-dispose of the object) - so don't use object-initializers with `IDisposable` types).

Comment: @Dai X and Y are members of the ECPoint struct that are in the System.Security.Cryptography namespace.  That's where they're defined and they're byte arrays.  Also, read/assigned to can be used in a "fairly" interchangle way in this example as the value of X and Y are read from a MemoryStream and assigned to the X and Y arrays.

Answer (score 3):

> My question is: Is it GUARANTEED that X will be read and initialized before Y?

**Yes**

*Object-Initializers* are defined in section 11.7.15.3 in [the current latest formal publication of the C# Language Specification](https://ecma-international.org/wp-content/uploads/ECMA-334_6th_edition_june_2022.pdf) (which, as of Q3 2023 is only C# 6.0 - [apparently Jon Skeet himself](https://ecma-international.org/task-groups/tc49-tg2/?tab=scope) is working on formalizing all of the *fun stuff* the C# LDT has added over the past 6-7 years).

Anyway, *as per the specification* (emphasis mine):

> An object initializer consists of **a sequence** of member initializers, enclosed by `{` and `}` tokens and separated by commas
> [...]
> A member initializer that specifies an expression after the equals sign **is processed in the same way as an assignment** (§11.18.2) to the target.
> [...]

I accept it isn't immediately clear, but if you infer exactly what "*sequence of member initializers*" means (i.e. that the listed properties will be initialized *in the same order as in the C# source code* listing) then the desired behaviour you're describing is guaranteed by the spec.

---

I note that the C# language specification document doesn't actually define the term "sequence" in this context (which initially made me doubt my own interpretation...), however if we read further on we'll see where the spec makes another reference to a *sequence* w.r.t. *anonymous-types* and how separate anonymous-type initializers are only considered to have identical types if their (object-initializer) properties are declared in the same order, otherwise they are distinct types (despite sharing same-named members)...

> Within the same program, two anonymous object initializers that specify **a sequence of properties** of the same names and compile-time types **in the same order** will produce instances of the same anonymous type.

...which is why this doesn't compile, because `x` and `y` are considered distinct types:

```cs
var x = GetT( () => new { X = 'a', Y = 123 } );
var y = GetT( () => new { Y = 123, X = 'b' } );

var both = new[]
{
    x,
    y   
};

static T GetT<T>( Func<T> getter )
{
    return getter();
}
```

...which I think gives us the assurances we need that the execution-order of the sequence of assignments in an object-initializer is well-defined.

Answer (score -1):

https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LglgNgNAJiDUAfAAgJgIwFgBQyAMABMugHQAiATgIYDuYAdgOYDcOyAzEagQGYD2fHAG8cBMQQAOFMADcqwAKYEACnwbBJa+sHSts4ydLmKVWjRLOo9BjrwEAKAJSjxI/QfEX16AgF4C9Ao0pupOBG4ekQQAGn4EALIKwAAWfDAAwlQQEE5QLlHiAJpxiSlpmdlO+R4AvtZRXtrc/oHBqqGO4dUFxf6lqRlZOY557gVisX1JAxXD3eJ11TXV1VKy8krqCdPlQ1VjXQcGAEpU9DB8ALYEFOdxrQSn51dO9ZHIAOw35yQAcgoAD2A9gALKhHG8CMtsDUgA==

^ Close to your example code that I wired up in sharplab.io
Should default to IL on the right.
If you scroll down to IL_0019 & IL_0027 you will see that X then Y is set for the point1.
Scroll a little further down you will see at IL_0044 and IL_0052 that Y then X is set for point2 because I reversed the initializer order.

Comment: You could also switch the right from IL to C# and see what the C# gets lowered to in C# (because most newer C# syntax is just syntax sugar that gets lowered it much older/more basic C#). You will see there as well that the lowered code follows the order in your initializer, so X will always be set before Y if you set X first.

Comment: The problem with your answer is that it isn't _authoritative_: you're just describing current compiler behaviour, which may-or-may-not be implementation-defined - your answer doesn't address the _hard-G_ (for _Guarantees_) asked by the OP. (FWIW, I did not downvote you)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to explain why.